# python giving NameError with global variable

Tags: python, nameerror

Can someone please help me understand why this is throwing a NameError? I'm defining and initializing 'cnt', then declaring it as a global, but I'm getting a NameError that 'cnt' is not defined.

```
def my_func():
  cnt = 0

  def add_one():
    global cnt
    cnt = cnt + 1

  print(cnt)
  add_one()
  print(cnt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, the variable has three scopes: local, nonlocal and global.

- A variable in a function, the variable's scope is local.
- A variable outside of a function, the variable's scope is global.
- For nested functions, if a variable is in the outer function, its scope is nonlocal for the inner function. If the inner function wants to access the variable in the outer function, need to use `nonlocal` keyword.

So, change `global cnt` to `nonlocal cnt`, the code will be work.

This document may help you understand variable scopes in python:
[Python Scope of Variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-scope-of-variables/)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

cnt is just in my_func() and add_one() can't find it. You should global it in My_func() and then add_one() can access it

```
def my_func():
  cnt = 0
  global cnt
  def add_one():
    cnt = cnt + 1

  print(cnt)
  add_one()
  print(cnt)
```